# absolute <img> doesn't show show up (is in the right position)

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to show an image in absolute positioning.
It's in the right place. http://gyazo.com/f1c545fe183c741d92c9466eacdbd020
it just doesn't show up, and I can't figure out why...

```
.active{
    background-color: #8b9dc3;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
}

.driehoek{
   position: absolute;
   left:28px;
   top:29px;
}

<ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#" ><span class="driehoek"><img src="images/navdriehoek.png" alt=""/></span>Home</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you've posted doesn't allow us to see the problem you have. Please post a complete code example.

Comment: @j08691: http://jsfiddle.net/9r4ou50m/ Here is my JSF, I hope you can do something with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to guess here. Looks like your absolutely positioned image is overlapped by content after it's parent element. Try adding `z-index: 10;` on `.driehoek` selector.

Or some of parent elements may have `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: And what about `overflow: hidden;`? As @j08691 said it's hard to tell without seeing actual markup.

Comment: it was indeed the overflow:hidden. Thank you!